# browserify with noparse=true - how it works

Tags: browserify

I would like to ask what is the purpose of using browserify with **noparse** option set to **true** (or how browserify works). For instance:

- if browserify does not parse files at all, does it means that it will not find **require** statements?
- if it does not find **require** statements, then how to force code to load module? For instance, I have **toastr** & **jQuery**. **toastr** requires **jQuery**. But when I used browserify to create a bundle with **noparse** set to **true**, and I added to this bundle both files:

`var bundler = browserify();
bundler.add('jquery.js');
bundler.add('toastr.js');
bundler.bundle();`

then I get the error, that jQuery module it not found.

Comment: Please show your usage of `noParse` in your example. Please also show an example of how toastr requires jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you bundle a file with browserify, it parses the file for `require()` calls so it can build a dependency graph and bundle the required files. The purpose of the `noParse` option is to skip that parsing when you don't need or want it. For example, if you're bundling a large library file like jQuery and you know it doesn't contain any `require()` calls that need to be processed, it will save time in bundling if you `noParse` that file. Also, it's currently difficult to `require()` a previously browserified bundle when making a new bundle. In that case you can sometimes resolve the issue by setting `noParse` for the previously browserified bundle.

> if browserify does not parse files at all, does it means that it will not find require statements?

Yes.